# Как из поля ввода получить два значения?

Tags: input, angular, angular-material

Есть форма, в которой поле ввода с автоподстановкой ФИО из списка. Соответственно, value этой формы является строкой, чтобы пользователь видел выбранного им человека

[image].

Вот код шаблона:

```
<form class="example-form" class="filter-form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" class="input-full-width">
    <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Выберите сотрудника"
    aria-label="Number"
    matInput [formControl]="myControl"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
      [value]="option.surname + ' ' + option.name + ' ' + option.middleName">
        {{option.surname}} {{option.name}} {{option.middleName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button type="submit" mat-raised-button class="btn-prim m-1">Добавить</button>
  <button type="button" mat-raised-button class="m-1" (click)="change(false)">Отмена</button>
  </form>
```

Обратите внимание, что в цикле *ngFor я получаю object из массива. И потом забираю его свойства для отображения в input.

Соответственно при получении в компоненте value из формы я получаю строку, а хотел бы - строку + object. По строке делать фильтрацию списка автоподстановки, а object использовать для его дальнейшей обработки в компоненте (например, добавить выбранного сотрудника в таблицу).

Как это сделать?

Конечно, есть способ: получить строку и в коде компонента отфильтровать из массива объект с такими строковыми значениями. Но этот вариант выглядит некрасиво.

Comment: не использовал, но может быть это Вам [поможет](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values), если я правильно понял то вам нужно свойство `displayWith`

Comment: да, похоже на то, что требуется

Comment: пока не могу подружить его с выводом списка и его фильтрацией...

Comment: вроде бы получается

Answer (score 1):

Добавил [displayWith]="displayFn" в шаблон компонента, как указано в примере.

Затем в код компонента добавил функцию:

```
  displayFn(option?: Person): string | undefined {
    return option ? option.surname + ' ' + option.name + ' ' + option.middleName : undefined;
  }
```

Она обеспечивает показ в поле ввода текстовых значений. При этом сам input передает в компонент выбранный object.

Также пришлось добавить валидацию value, так как если начинаешь вводить в поле какие-то символы и они не соответствуют никакому объекту, то value приходить в виде строки.